# Android Wear keyboard Input Method

Tags: android, keyboard, wear-os

for my Android Wear app I need a Keyboard to enter text. I do not want to use the Microphone Input of the Google Voice Service.

I found a nice tutorial on how to do Custom Keyboards on android (http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-keyboard-on-android--cms-22615 )
and tried it out on Android Wear. However since you cannot choose the Input Method in the settings, the Keyboard wont get inflated on Input fields.

I found out that there already are some keyboards for Android Wear like the "Minuum" or the "Analog Keyboard for Android Wear". So it must be possible somehow to do a custom Keyboard for the Watch.

I can test the app on an Samsung Gear Live and Sony Smartwatch 3 but on neither of them it is working yet.
Does someone know how to program a Custom Keyboard for the Android Wear?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Do the steps as follows:
1. Open [Debug] mode on your android wear device.
2. connect your wear device to a computer via USB.
3. Open a command line window, and navigate to ADB directory.
4. using this command to install your signed IME apk. "adb install ime.apk"
5. activate your input method. "adb shell ime enable com.example.xxx/.yourInputServiceName"
6. set your ime as default. "adb shell ime set com.example.xxx/.yourInputServiceName"

This is the only way you can use your ime on android wear. There are two reasons why:
1. Android wear disabled the input & language setting activity, so you can not call it as you can do so on android phone.
2. Due to security reason, you can not run adb shell commands from inside of your app, for example, using the following code will give you a security exception.
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ime enable ......").

But, may be you can change your app to be a systme app rather than a user app. How to do it? I dont know. If you got answer, please tell me.